# A manga about a skilled surgeon who operates on the president's heart and removes worm-like parasites in the first chapter

Tags: super-doctor-k

I am quite sure I read the localized version of the manga about 10 years ago, so the manga must have started serialization in Japan many years before that.

The manga started with the president being injected something into his hand, and fell into coma. All the doctors tried many types of drugs to no avail. The protagonist, who was a great doctor and surgeon, somehow came to operate on the president. It wa revealed that the president's [pericardial cavity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pericardial_cavity) (the space between the double-walled sac containing the hear) was inhibited by a bunch of worm-like parasites, and he would die if the parasites were left to multiply, since it would obstruct the heart's beating. In the surgery, the protagonist had to stop the heart of the president and skillfully used a small clip to pick all the parasites, then restarted his heart. He also ordered to filter president's blood to remove all traces of the parasite in the blood stream.

Can anyone help me identify this manga?

Comment: It sounds like *Black Jack*. That's the only one I can think of that was serialized 10 years ago.

Comment: Does a story like the one described by the OP happen in Black Jack? If so, could you add information about this? At the moment, the only thing I see supporting your answer is that Black Jack is indeed a doctor, which isn't really sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

After googling to no avail, I tried searching for "surgeon" on [mangaupdates](http://www.mangaupdates.com) and go through the list of result. Among the results, [*K2*](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=14199) has a similar art style, but the synopsis is a bit different from what I remembered, so I check out the prequels [*Super Doctor K*](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=44137) and [*Doctor K*](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=47084) via Google and found the manga I was looking for in Vietnamese.

The image below is from volume 1 chapter 4 showing parasites on the heart:

[image: Parasites outside the heart]

Since I still don't know the exact title of the manga, I check the Wikipedia article of [*Super Doctor K*](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BCK). The manga was serialized from 1988 to 1998. While the series' name stayed unchanged in the magazine, it was changed to *Doctor K* for tankoubon released after 1996. The synopsis of *Doctor K* on Wikipedia matches the description in the question:

> アメリカ合衆国大統領ジム・ハミルトンが何者かの手によって瀕死の重傷となる。容疑者はドクターK。犯行の裏には何が?そして一昭の計画とは?KAZUYAの物語に終止符が打たれる。

Translation

> Jim Hamilton, the President of the United States, is suspended between life and death after receiving a serious injury from unknown person. The suspect is Doctor K. What is the motive behind the crime? And what is Kazuaki's plan? Starts the final arc of KAZUYA's story.